# Functional equation $f(x) = f(3x) + \tanh(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

The equation itself:
$$f(x) = f(3x) + \tanh(x)$$
So firstly I'm solving homogeneous equation:
$$f(x)=f(3x)$$ 
so is just periodic function $\Theta(\ln x)$ with period $\ln 3$. So:
$$F(x) = \Theta(\ln x) + \hat{f}(x)$$where $\hat{f}(x)$ is the particular solution of equation. Any tips how  to find some?

Upd: New picture[image]

It seems like its really bad around 0, but going smooth on big values.
And my current guess that its behavior around $x=0$ is strongly connected to period of $\Theta$

Comment: never mind, I just saw the title :p

Comment: Around zero, I would do a telescoping infinite sum like this: $f(\frac{x}{3^{n+1}})=f(\frac{x}{3^{n}})+\tanh(\frac{x}{3^{n+1}}) $ No?

Comment: For a suitable domain, you can sum on the telescoping series to get: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} f(\frac{x}{3^{n+1}})-f(\frac{x}{3^{n}}) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \tanh(\frac{x}{3^{n+1}}) = f(0)-f(x)$ Of course this is true assuming $f$ is continuous which is garanteed I guess because of the equation involving $\tanh$ which is in turn continuous. This might give a hint on how the particular solution might be constructed.

Comment: Try to replace $'x'$ by $\tanh^{-1}(x)$

Comment: @BarryCipra, it's only true if the function is continuos.

Comment: @BarryCipra, since the question raised from another one I have some view of function and a bit more knowledge of the question. I just realized it's important. I made new numerical analysis, this function is oscillating for x close to 0(about 0.001). And it seems to be discountinios at 0.

Comment: @EzWin, I have deleted my comments (the first being no longer relevant, the second being a bit beside the point) and posted an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For functions $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, the general solution to the functional equation

$$f(x)=f(3x)+\tanh(x)$$

is

$$f(x)=\Theta(\ln x)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\tanh\left(x\over3^k\right)$$

where $\Theta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is any function satisfying $\Theta(x+\ln3)=\Theta(x)$.

Note that the infinite series is absolutely convergent for any $x$, since $\tanh(x/3^k)\approx x/3^k$ for large enough $k$.  It defines a continuous (indeed, smooth) function on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  If you want the function $f(x)$ to have a limit as $x\to0^+$, then you need for $\Theta$ to be constant; otherwise $f$ will approach all the values $\Theta$ takes on (as in the OP's figure).