# Approximation of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} \tanh(3^n x)$ in $x = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations

I want to (asymptotic function) approximate the series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} \tanh(3^n x)$ around $x = 0$.

I found the equation for $f(x)$:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\ f(3x) + \tanh(x)$$

for $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}f(3x) \Rightarrow f(x) = A\ x^{\log_32}$

let $A = A(x) \Rightarrow A(x) = \Theta(\ln(x))$ where $\Theta(x) $ any function with period $\ln3$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @orlp how to approximate this sum

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I've been playing around with this numerically in Mathematica, and it *looks* like $f(x) \approx a x^p$ for small $x>0$, where $a\approx 3.71549$ and $p$ is suspiciously close to $\ln(2) / \ln(3) \approx 0.63093$. (Of course we know that looks can be deceiving.)

Comment: I find analytically (with the aid of numerics) that for small $x$, $f(x) \approx a\, x^{\ln 2 / \ln 3} - 2 x$, where $a \approx 3.71549$. I can't figure out what that value for $a$ is.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288424/functional-equation-fx-f3x-tanhx)?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative justification for the $\log_3 2$ exponent is as follows: suppose we want to approximate $f$ by some $x^a$, where $a>0$ so that $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{-a}f(x)=c$ with $0<c<\infty$. The functional equation shows 
$$c=\frac {3^a}2c+\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }a<1 \\ 1 &\text{if } a=1 \\ \infty & \text{if }a>1\end{cases}$$
Which forces $a<1$ and $a=\log_3 2$.

Given this value of $a$, instead of looking at $\lim x^{-a}f(x)$ as $x\to 0$ we look at $F(x)=3^{-ax}f(3^x)=2^{-x}f(3^x)$ as $x\to -\infty$. Putting $g(x)=2^{-x}\tanh(3^x)$ shows $F(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}g(x+n)$. Because $g(x)\le(\frac 32)^x$, $\sum_{n\le 1} g(x+n)\le 2(\frac 32)^x$ and thus $\bar F(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}g(x+n)$ tends to $F$ as $x\to -\infty$. But $\bar F$ has period $1$ so all information about it can be gleaned from its behavior on $[0,1]$.

Since we also have $g(x)\le 2^{-x}$, for any $x$ in the unit interval, $g(x+n)\le 2^{1-n}$ and $g(x-n)\le (\frac 32)^{1-n}$ so that 
$$\left|\bar F(x)-\sum_{-N}^N g(x+n)\right|\le 2^{1-N}+3\left(\frac 23\right)^N $$
Therefore, the series converges uniformly, and does so at a geometric rate. This means one can obtain a very good approximation for $\bar F$ and this in turn approximates $F$ in the limit.